# How to query CodeIgniter in two table with condition?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

I got headache of this query issue in CodeIgniter
I'm a beginner of this framework

[image]

How to query in CodeIgniter of Query result in Table 1 and Table 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Query Builder in Codeigniter version 3 (I assume since your using the tag `codeigniter-3`), then you could specify the columns in your select statement and use join to achieve what you want:

```
$this->db->select('t1.Account, t1.Client, t1.Wala, t2.Meron');
$this->db->from('Table1 t1');
$this->db->join('Table2 t2', 't1.Account = t2.Account AND t1.Client = t2.Client');
$this->db->where('t1.Account', 111); // IF YOU ONLY WANT A SPECIFIC ACCOUNT
$this->db->group_by('t1.Account, t1.Client');
$query = $this->db->get();
   
if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
  $result = $query->result(); // ARRAY OF OBJECTS
  foreach ($result as $r){
    echo $r->Account."\t";
    echo $r->Client."\t";
    echo $r->Wala."\t";
    echo $r->Meron."\n";                
  }
}
```

The result:

```
| Account | Client | Wala | Meron |
|---------|--------|------|-------|
|   111   |  Doe   |      |  50   |
|   111   |  Jhon  | 200  |  50   |
```

Documentation: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Alternatively, you can use a pure SQL query to get the same result:

```
$sql = 'SELECT t1.Account, t1.Client, t1.Wala, t2.Meron
        FROM Table1 t1 
        JOIN Table2 t2 
          ON t1.Account = t2.Account AND t1.Client = t2.Client 
        WHERE t1.Account = 111 
        GROUP BY t1.Account, t1.Client';
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

If you are using MySQL > 5.6 then use the group by function any_value():

```
t1.Account, t1.Client, ANY_VALUE(t1.Wala), ANY_VALUE(t2.Meron)
```

To be used with caution since unexpected results may appear if you have multiple rows with different values in the columns "Wala" or "Meron" for the same Account and Client.

Comment: What you have is right on the previous data and query. I'm sorry I change my table data and query result, How can I query in that case again!

Comment: OK, I have updated the answer. You can use a join between the two tables based on the Account and Client columns to achieve what you want @Richard.

Comment: I have try your solution but its the same output as before
the <b>Wala</> column 200 still filling up the empty to 200.

Comment: @Richard. Strange. I have tested the solution on my machine and it works. Do you have any more columns in the two tables? Any primary key? What database do you use and what are the data types of your db fields?

Comment: Click on the run button to run the SQL query: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eUx23qq31EWqQ3x9WfwPWL/0

Comment: Thanks man, I was wonder why it is not working on my MySQL but when I try on fiddle is working...

Comment: If you are running MySQL > 5.6 then try the GROUP BY function ANY_VALUE() to see if it works better: `t1.Account, t1.Client, ANY_VALUE(t1.Wala), ANY_VALUE(t2.Meron)`